# ADO.NET EF - can't establish DB connection using VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I'm following this tutorial : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542 for `Code First` basics using `ADO.NET EF`. The problem is that when executing the code the DataBase is not created automatically and I think that this is because the configurations in my `app.config` but it's my first day with real code and I can't figure out how to adjust my config file so I can connect to my server and use a created DataBase if neccessary or let the program from the tutorial create new database as expected from what is written.

This is my `App.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
  <!--  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory> -->


    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="BloggingContext"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            connectionString="server=milka-pc\sqlserver2012;Database=Panorama;user id=MyID;password=MyPass;port=3333;Integrated Security=True;"/>
    </connectionStrings>

    <!--<contexts>
      <context type=" Blogging.BloggingContext, MyAssembly">
        <databaseInitializer type="Blogging.MyCustomBlogInitializer, MyAssembly" />
      </context>
    </contexts>-->


  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

As you can see some parts are commented as I tried a various things to make it work.

This is how y server explorer looks like while I'm trying to connect:

[image]

Also since I have zero experience with ViasualStudioXXXX and connecting to DataBases this is what I see and how I select my server:

[image]

There in `milka-pc\sqlserver2012` I have a DB named `Panorama` which I can use or better follow the tutorial step by step and leave the program to create my new DB. For now I can't neither of these two. And to connect to `milka-pc\sqlserver2012` I need to provied `UserName` and `Password` which I did in `App.config`. I say this just to know that these fields are not blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that milka-pc\sqlserver2012 is in fact working on port 3333 as you suggested

change your connectionstring to this:

```
<add name="BloggingContext"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="server=milka-pc\sqlserver2012,3333;Database=Panorama;user id=MyID;password=MyPass;Integrated Security=True;"/>
```

Just to make sure try that connection string in you SQL management studio with provided credentials.

If that doesnt work consult your sql server configuration manager, specifically under SQL server Network configuration make sure that your instance has enabled TCP/IP pipe with appropriate port enabled.

Cheers.